# How to give download option in vimeo player in reactnative?

Tags: react-native, vimeo-player

So I am designing an reactnative app where I need to embed vimeo video player. 
Can I give my users an option to download the video for offline mode ?
How can I restrict the downloaded file in app itself like netflix does?
Is that possible? PLease guide.